# Levenshtein Edit Distance is not calculating edit distance

Tags: c++, algorithm, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I am trying to get my Levenshtein Edit Distance algorithm working but for some reason, the number of edits is coming out incorrect. I can't see where my mistake is and I was wondering if someone see's what I am doing incorrectly.

> Input

```
5
ATCGTT
AGTTAC
ACGAAT
CCGTAAAT
TTACGACCAGT
```

> expected output

```
Strand A: ATCGTT--
Strand B: A--GTTAC
Edit Distance: 4

Strand A: ATCG-TT
Strand B: A-CGAAT
Edit Distance: 3

Strand A: ATCGT---T
Strand B: -CCGTAAAT
Edit Distance: 5

Strand A: AT-CG----TT
Strand B: TTACGACCAGT
Edit Distance: 7

Strand A: AGTTAC
Strand B: ACGAAT
Edit Distance: 4

Strand A: -AGT-TAC
Strand B: CCGTAAAT
Edit Distance: 5

Strand A: --A-G-TTA-C
Strand B: TTACGACCAGT
Edit Distance: 8

Strand A: ACG--AAT
Strand B: CCGTAAAT
Edit Distance: 3

Strand A: --ACGA--A-T
Strand B: TTACGACCAGT
Edit Distance: 5

Strand A: --CCG-TAAAT
Strand B: TTACGACCAGT
Edit Distance: 7
```

> my output

```
Strand A: ATCGT-
Strand B: AGTTAC
Edit Distance: 5

Strand A: ATC-T-
Strand B: ACGAAT
Edit Distance: 5

Strand A: ATC-T-
Strand B: CCGTAAAT
Edit Distance: 5

Strand A: A-C-T-
Strand B: TTACGACCAGT
Edit Distance: 10

Strand A: AGTTAC
Strand B: ACGAAT
Edit Distance: 5

Strand A: AG-TAC
Strand B: CCGTAAAT
Edit Distance: 6

Strand A: A--T-C
Strand B: TTACGACCAGT
Edit Distance: 7

Strand A: AC-AAT
Strand B: CCGTAAAT
Edit Distance: 7

Strand A: AC---T
Strand B: TTACGACCAGT
Edit Distance: 8

Strand A: CC-TAAAT
Strand B: TTACGACCAGT
Edit Distance: 8
```

> findEditDistance

```
void EditDistance::findEditDistance()
{
    int upperValue, leftValue, diagonalValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < mLengthX; ++i)
    {
        table[i][0].stringLength = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mLengthY; ++i)
    {
        table[0][i].stringLength = i;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < mLengthX; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < mLengthY; ++j)
        {
            if (mStringX[i] == mStringY[j])
            {
                table[i][j].direction = DIAGONAL;
                table[i][j].stringLength = table[i - 1][j -1].stringLength;
            }
            else
            {
                upperValue = table[i - 1][j].stringLength;
                leftValue = table[i][j - 1].stringLength;
                diagonalValue = table[i - 1][j - 1].stringLength;

                if (upperValue < leftValue)
                {
                    if (upperValue < diagonalValue)
                    {
                        //upper is the lowest
                        table[i][j].stringLength = table[i - 1][j].stringLength + 1;
                        table[i][j].direction = UP;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //diagonal is lowest
                        table[i][j].stringLength = table[i - 1][j -1].stringLength + 1;
                        table[i][j].direction = DIAGONAL;
                    }
                }
                else if (leftValue < diagonalValue)
                {
                    //left is lowest
                    table[i][j].stringLength = table[i][j - 1].stringLength + 1;
                    table[i][j].direction = LEFT;
                }
                else
                {
                    //diagonal is lowest
                    table[i][j].stringLength = table[i - 1][j -1].stringLength + 1;
                    table[i][j].direction = DIAGONAL;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

> getDistance

```
void EditDistance::getDistance()
{
    int i = mStringX.length() - 1;
    int j = mStringY.length() - 1;

    numEdits = 0;

    updateStrands (i, j);
}
```

> updateStrands

```
void EditDistance::updateStrands (int i, int j)
{
    if (i == 0 || j == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (table[i][j].direction == DIAGONAL)
    {
        ++numEdits;
        updateStrands (i - 1, j - 1);
    }
    else if (table[i][j].direction == UP)
    {
        mStringY[j] = '-';
        ++numEdits;
        updateStrands (i - 1, j);
    }
    else
    {
        mStringX[i] = '-';
        ++numEdits;
        updateStrands (i, j - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide what your input and output vs expected output was?

Comment: Oh yeah I can do that. Let me do that really quick

Comment: You've only posted one set of outputs.

Comment: Could you tell us which ones are incorrect, and what the correct answers ought to have been? It would save us some time.

Comment: Try printing the whole distance table - it will help you debug the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the edit distance is in your `updateStrands`. It counts diagonal moves as 1, when in fact a diagonal move can have a distance of 1 (substitution) or 0 (match). You could fix this in `updateStrands`, but there's really no need to do the calculation there at all, when the number is already in the lower-right corner of `table`.

If you want the correct "strands" (e.g. "ATCGTT--" and "A--GTTAC"), you will have to make corrections in `updateStrands` (you *change* elements of the strings where you should *insert*), `getDistance` (you start in the wrong place) and `findEditDistance` (you neglect to assign values to `direction` along the upper and left edges when you set `stringLength` to `i`).